# Meteor - Collections schema advice needed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I need some advice here.

Im working with jquery sortable lists. Ive got two collections 'users' and lists'. User is able to add new
lists aswell as new users, then moves them around. I want to know which user is in which list. I have two options.
Either list in 'lists' collection will contain all users which belong to that list, or user in 'users' collection would
have a field like: 'list' ( they belongs to ). I chose the second option, which in my opinion would give me more
flexibilty ( im no expert ), but I encountered a problem. When a user will add a new list I will end up without a helper
for that list.

What do you guys think? Which solution is better here? And if there's any way to go around the problem I met ?

Comment: I would like to suggest you to use the Roles packages for achieving what you are looking to do. Here is a link to it and more description: https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles 

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, i want those users to be like regular items in the list, and dont want to create accounts for them, as they will not be able to log in.

Comment: Btw. I think I could resolve the problem with helper with like main, general helper which would get the name of current list and based on that do {{#each}}. But not quite sure how to get that name.